# How to compare two strings in scala?

Tags: string, scala, equality

I want to compare two strings in scala. for example,

My Strings are:

```
scala java
scala java c++
scala c++
```

I want to compare the string

" **scala c++**"  with each strings

Results should be,

```
scala c++ = scala java   // false
scala c++ = scala java c++  // false
scala c++ = scala c++   // true
```

Comment: And what would be an example that returns true?

Comment: Why is the last test supposed to return `false`?

Answer (score 58):

In Scala you can use `==` for equality

```
scala> "scala c++" == "scala java"
res0: Boolean = false
scala> "scala c++" == "scala java c++"
res1: Boolean = false
scala> "scala c++" == "scala c++"
res2: Boolean = true
```

The == method is defined in the AnyRef class. Since the methods first checks for null values, and then calls the equals method on the first object to see if the two objects are equals you dont have to do a special null check;

```
"test" == null
res0: Boolean = false
```

See the [Scala getting started guide](http://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started.html) and [strings](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/strings.html)

From "[An Overview of the Scala Programming Language
Second Edition](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaOverview.pdf)";

> "The equality operation **==** between values is designed to be
>   transparent with respect to the type's representation. For value
>   types, it is the natural (numeric or boolean) equality. For reference
>   types, **==** is treated as an alias of the **equals** method from
>   **java.lang.Object**. That method is originally defined as reference
>   equality, *but is meant to be overridden in subclasses to implement the
>   natural notion of equality for these subclasses*. For instance, the
>   boxed versions of value types would implement an equals method which
>   compares the boxed values. By contrast, in Java, == always means
>   reference equality on reference types. While this is a bit more
>   efficient to implement, it also introduces a serious coherence problem
>   because boxed versions of equal values might no longer be equal with
>   respect to ==. Some situations require reference equality instead of
>   user-dened equality. An example is hash-consing, where eciency is
>   paramount. For these cases, class **AnyRef** defines an additional **eq**
>   method, which cannot be overridden, and is implemented as reference
>   equality (i.e., it behaves like
>   **==** in Java for reference types)."

Comment: This single refinement takes away so much `java` pain!

Answer (score 3):

To add to equality comparison, you can use `!=` for inequality.